# Jquery + ccs3 transition on background-position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have written some code which allows me to use css3 to add a transition to the movement of a background image on click. My code says "on click add 874px to the x value of the background position". This works perfectly until i add my transition on the item because it then allows the user to click during the transition which breaks my scenes. I only want the user to view multiples of 874px. Is there a better way I can do this rather than a timeout? I want the user to be able to click multiple times but to only reach the nearest multiple of 874px.

Hope that makes some sense. Thank you for any help. [JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/UBBCJ/15/)

HTML

```
<div class="container">    
    <div class="decoration two"></div>
    <div class="decoration one"></div>

    <span id="btnPrev" class="prev">prev</span>
    <span id="btnNext" class="next">next</span>
</div>
```

JS

```
var btnPrev = $("#btnPrev");
var btnNext = $("#btnNext");

var decorationOne =$(".decoration.one");
var decorationTwo =$(".decoration.two");

$(function () {

    btnNext.click(function() {
        var DOG = decorationOne.css('background-position');
        var splat = DOG.replace(/[^-\d\. ]/g, '').split(" ");
        var new_values = [parseFloat(splat[0]) - 874 + "px", parseFloat(splat[1]) + 0 +"px"]; // x, y
        decorationOne.css('background-position', new_values.join(" "));

    });
    btnPrev.click(function() {
        var DOG = decorationOne.css('background-position');
        var splat = DOG.replace(/[^-\d\. ]/g, '').split(" ");
        var new_values = [parseFloat(splat[0]) + 874 + "px", parseFloat(splat[1]) + 0 +"px"]; // x, y
        decorationOne.css('background-position', new_values.join(" "));

    });
});
```

CSS

```
.container {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #E7F3FF;
    border: 4px solid blue;
    border-radius: 16px 16px 16px 16px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.2);
    color: #054B98;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 35px 0 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 874px;
}
.decoration {
    position: absolute;
}
.decoration.one {
    background: url("http://s22.postimg.org/ljly8r7tr/hills_1.png") repeat scroll left 0 transparent;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 500px;
    -webkit-transition: background-position 1s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: background-position 1s ease 0s;
    transition: background-position 1s ease 0s;
    width: 2622px;
}
.decoration.two {
    background: blue;
    bottom: -180px;
    height: 472px;
    width: 5760px;
}
.prev {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 20px;
}
.next {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make use of the `animationend` event (MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations#Adding_the_animation_event_listeners). Basically set a var true when you start the animation and then don't execute again until the `animaitonend` event sets it back to false

I misunderstood. You can maintain an index variable and calculate based on that rather than using the current `background-position` value which might be mid-transition. The click events will always have access to the index variable even if they fire 20 minutes from now.

```
var btnPrev = $("#btnPrev");
var btnNext = $("#btnNext");

var decorationOne =$(".decoration.one");
var decorationTwo =$(".decoration.two");


$(function () {

    var index = 0;

    btnNext.click(function() {

        index = index + 1; //you'll also probably want to check it's not over a max
        decorationOne.css('background-position', (index * 874) + 'px 0px'); //assuming y is always 0

    });
    btnPrev.click(function() {

        index = index - 1; //you'll also probably want to check it's not under 0
        decorationOne.css('background-position', (index * 874) + 'px 0px'); //assuming 

    });
});
```

Comment: I know I could do that but I want the user to be able to click multiple times but to only reach the nearest multiple of 874px.

Comment: Maybe keep an index in js and calculate based on that rather than what the current background position is, or calculate the previous 874x cut off (based on current) before adding the new 874.

Comment: I am pretty new to this, I am using it as a learning exercise. IS there any starting point you could point me in?

Comment: I've edited to show using an index, let me know if that works for you

Comment: Thank you very much Matt, I will crack on with that